# Is there a way to generate a Hash Function which returns hash code of type signed long long?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, long-integer

I need a function which can take string as an input and generate hash code out of it. Currently, in c++ we have std::hash to do this but this returns the hash code of type size_t( unsigned long long ). Here, I need a hash function which can give me the hash code of type signed long long.

I have also tried using the modulus operator but that gives me negative values and those are not reliable. Hence, pls advise me on the hash function I can use in C++ so that I get hash code of type signed long long.

Comment: Since `hash % n_buckets` cannot be a negative number (without invoking *Undefined Behavior*) -- why would you want to return a signed number?

Comment: take your favorite `signed long long toSigned(unsigned long long)`, and apply it to the result of `std::hash`

Comment: @Caleth, there is no function by the name toSigned in C++..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I tried (hash % std::numeric_limits<signed long long>::max() ), but this also gave me negative values due to overflow. Can you please explain your logic in a bit detailed way?...

Comment: When working with a hash table, you have an array of `n` pointers to your node type for the table. The number of pointers (elements) are referred to as the number of "buckets" for the table. When you hash a value, you create some unique number that you then modulo by `n`, e.g. `hash % n`. That tells you which bucket (element) the node goes in. Since your node is a node for a linked-list, in the event of a collision, you chain the nodes together with the node in the bucket as the *head* node in the list. Since `hash % n` cannot be negative (no negative array indexes), using signed is odd.

Comment: You may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a hash function which can give me the hash code of type `signed long long`.

You could just set to 0 the most significant bit, unless your architecture have a weird internal representation of integral types, this would produce a positive number when converted to signed type of the same size.

```
template <class S>
constexpr size_t clamp_to_positive(size_t value)
{
    return value & (std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() >> 
        (std::numeric_limits<size_t>::digits - std::numeric_limits<S>::digits)
    );
}
```

You can then call it as

```
auto my_hash = clamp_to_positive<long long>(std::hash<std::string>{}(source_string));
```

---

As noted by [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt), though, the easiest way is to just right-shift by one the unsigned value.

```
auto my_hash = static_cast<long long>(std::hash<std::string>{}(source_string) >> 1);
```

---

Another way to tackle this problem is to force the modulo operation to always return a positive value.

```
// Evaluates abs(x) as an unsigned type, avoiding corner case overflow.
template <class T>
constexpr auto unsigned_abs(T x)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>);
    if constexpr ( std::is_unsigned_v<T> ) {
        return x;
    }
    return x < 0
        ? ~static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>(x) + 1 
        : static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>(x);
}

// Evaluates abs(x) % abs(y) avoiding overflows. The result has the same type
// of y and it's always   0 <= result < y. It has UB when y == 0.
template <class X, class Y> 
auto absolute_remainder(X x, Y y)
{
    static_assert( std::is_integral_v<X> && std::is_integral_v<Y> );
    return static_cast<Y>(unsigned_abs(x) % unsigned_abs(y));
}
```

Whether you really need one of those or maybe a change in the current design of your program is left to you to figure out.

Comment: Hi @Bob, can you please breakdown the above logic and explain a bit. Looks a bit confusing to me..

Comment: @ShailendraPatil The idea is to get an unsigned value, move around the bits somehow (here I just xor the most significant bit with the the less one) to try to keep the statistically properties ofthe hash (which may be very poor with `std::hash`, depending on the implementation) and then return a signed (but still positive) value. If your types have a two's complement representation (quite common these days), masking the bits of the unsigned value, removing (setting to zero) its most significant bit it's enough. Note that this isn't equal to abs().

Comment: A much easier way to generate a number with a clear MSB is to (unsigned) right-shift by one.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point, thanks. Overthinking a solution is always a bad idea.

Comment: @BenVoigt, for each unique string, will the hash code generated by the method of right shift be unique at any given time?...

Comment: @ShailendraPatil If the string are of *arbitrary* lengths, a finite sized hash can't be unique in the first place, there will always be collisions. If you are asking whether there still be a deterministic relation between a string an a unique hash, yes, if the hash is deterministic, the shift preserve that. You just have half the possible hashes, now.